# How to remove patched dependency in python unit tests

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

Given the following unit test

```
@patch("requests.get")
def test_create_resource_success(self, request_get):
    request_get_mock.return_value = Mock(ok=True)
    request_get_mock.return_value.json.return_value = {'key': 'value'}
    success = create_resource(data)
    self.assertTrue(success)
```

How do I make sure that all other unit tests usages of requests.get are not patched? How do I reset the patching in the tearDown?

Comment: you don't need to, that's literally what patch does

Comment: @wim i noticed it's affecting my other unit tests, if i run all, some would fail because requests.get is still mocked. If I run the those affected failing tests individually they would succeed.

Comment: The problem is somewhere else in your test suite, not with this patch decorator.

Comment: @alegria did you find a solution for your problem?

Comment: @Leoncino , i just remember wim is right the patch is doing it already, I believe I just fixed something else in my test. But I honestly can't remember now , apologies, i should have updated it here :(

Comment: No problem! I realized that my mock had been called within the same unittest, so I reset it by using ".reset_mock()" which can be applied to your patch :) Other than that it seems to be possible using patch.stop(), which stops the patch.